# Como instalar magento em virtual host?

Tags: ubuntu, magento

Estou tentando instalar o magento em meu localhost usando virtual host (para que possa funcionar) porém mesmo eu já criando o arquivo em `/etc/apache2/sites-available` com o nome `magento.conf` com o código:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/magento
<Directory /var/www/magento/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Caso eu tente acessar `http://magento.localhost` a pagina do apache é carregada normalmente `Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page` e os arquivos da pasta não abrem para que eu possa iniciar a instalação do magento.

alguém tem ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 0):

Adicione a opção `ServerName` dentro do seu `vhost`, e verifique se a opção `NameVirtualHost` esta habilitada (este parâmetro é global):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName magento.localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/magento
    <Directory /var/www/magento/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Fora isso, não vejo problemas.

Comment: `<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot “/var/www/magento”
    ServerName magento.localhost
    ServerAlias magento.localhost
    ErrorLog “/var/log/apache2/virtual-error.log”
    CustomLog “/var/log/apache2/virtual-custom.log” common
 
    <Directory “/var/www/magento/”>
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

assim?

Comment: O `ServerAlias` é desnecessário pois você esta criando um alias igual ao nome do servidor (mas acho que isso não é problema). Não esqueça de verificar se o parâmetro `NameVirtualHost` esta configurado corretamente. De resto, parece estar correto sim, considerando que os caminhos todos são válidos.

Comment: Fiz algumas mudanças aqui e agora a pagina mostra o erro: You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Comment: @RafaelAcioly verifique as permissões ao diretório `/var/www/magento` e seus arquivos. Verifique o usuário que o Apache esta executando: ele deve possuir permissões de leitura no diretório do vhost e seus arquivos. Se quiser fazer um teste fácil, libere completamente as permissões utilizando `chmod -R 777 /var/www/magento`. Depois que funcionar, restrinja novamente as permissões para um valor mais seguro.